# How does Mother Base staff morale work?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I'm been visiting Mother Base a lot to meet and beat my soldiers. These create messages that staff morale has increased. What does staff morale do, what are the ways to make it increase and decrease, and can I see my current staff morale somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Staff Morale effects your soldiers abilities. When they are in good morale, they will perform better than their skills, indicated by a yellow boost to their bars:
[image: staff management]

The primary factor for Morale is GMP balance. Keeping a surplus is the best way to ensure that Morale is not negatively effected. You can also visit the soldiers individually at Mother Base to raise their morale.

[Guide](http://mmgn.com/ps4/articles--the-phantom-pain-mother-base-upgrade-guide) + [Article](http://www.gameskinny.com/5wxep/check-out-all-these-cool-new-features-revealed-in-metal-gear-solid-vs-mother-base-demo)