# Will negative GMP and positive online GMP still hurt morale?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Resources in MGS 5 shared between offline and online mode and most of resources are stored online. However offline funds spent first and dip into negative values.

Andswer on [How does Mother Base staff morale work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/234256/20757) states that negative GMP values hurt morale.

Will morale decrease when offline resources negative but shared GMP value positive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The online resources can be viewed as a sort of "savings fund".

It seems that you are given a set amount that you can keep offline at a time and once this set amount drops to zero it will transfer more to you the next time you connect to the servers or hit checkpoints in or between missions.

So when your offline resources drop and there is no more online resources to feed in, that is when the staff moral will drop.

If your offline resources are negative but your online positive, some online resources should get transferred over.

Comment: I will check it, thanks. Right now, i observed, that after ordering upgrades offline funds are negative, i. e. -200k while online positive, 2000k

Comment: Hopefully, when you hit a checkpoint or log out / log in next, you should see some transfer over.

Comment: Mine transferred over pretty quickly, like, pretty much as soon as I did anything in game.

Comment: @LoboDemon, Yes, you are right, I spent money in chopper, then when i deployed to platform, offline gmp gain some balance and got out of red.

Answer (score -1):

If the servers need maintenance before you can get resources transferred you're boned unless you sell some stuff at mother base or whatever.